# Convert htaccess to nginx.conf

Tags: apache, nginx

Hi i have to convert this into nginx.conf directives, but something doesn't work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|robots\.txt|\.ico|\.woff|\.woff2|.ttf|\.svg)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|assets|landing|storage|installer|js|custom)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

This is my last try (nginx.conf translated):

```
autoindex off;

location ~* 
(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|robots\.txt|\.ico|\.woff|\.woff2|.ttf|\.svg)$ {
}

location ~ /public/ {
}

location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /%1 redirect;
    }
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
    }
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/(css|assets|landing|storage|installer|js|custom)/(.*)$ /public/$1/$2 break;
    }
}
```

But this way i get a loop error on my website..

I have also another .htaccess file placed in another folder and it is this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But the problem is still there